# Qgis: work in pyqgis from an external idle

Tags: pyqgis, idle, qgis-python-console

I'm writing a python script but, at the moment, I do everything from the Qgis python console.
Is there a way to write and run a pyqgis script externally from Qgis?

I'm using Qgis 2.18 and python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04 OS.

Comment: Is your python code designed to run *within* a running qgis, perhaps manipulating layers already loaded? Then use your IDE to edit and save, and then `import mything; mything.dostuff()` from the console is all you need. Write your code as a python module.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to try installing and configuring Pycharm. There's an [blog article here : How to setup PyCharm for QGIS development (under Debian/Ubuntu)](https://blog.qtibia.ro/2016/06/09/how-to-setup-pycharm-for-qgis-development-under-linux-and-windows/) describing how to configure all this.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install anaconda from here https://www.continuum.io/downloads.

open the python shell of anaconda Type this command to install qgis

```
conda install -c conda-forge qgis
```

The you can import qgis in python

if the above solution does not workout well for you, try this in your python console.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\Lib")

import qgis.core
```

change the qgis path as per your config

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a fundamental aspect, my operating system is ubuntu 16.04

Comment: How do you want to use it in python shell or in jupyter or any other way.

Comment: Say I'm a neophyte, what I would do is write the code and run it externally from the Qgis python console. Working on the console is extremely uncomfortable if the code is very long.

Comment: I'm sorry, none of these solutions work, I will continue with the integrated console in Qgis